# What images will I need to deploy an Android Application?

Tags: android, graphics, google-play, app-store

I am trying to collect a list of all image types, sizes, DPI, and "image reason" needed to deploy a fully functional android app on Google Play.

The reason I need this is so I can go to my graphics designer, once, and only once for this request.

I've put this togeher

```
Description                 Description  URL
Hi Res Icon       512   512 Play Store  https://play.google.com/apps/publish
Feature Graphic   320   180 Play Store  
Promo Graphic     180   120 play Store  
TV Banner         320   180 play Store  
Promo Video                 Play Store  
Consent Screen    120   120 If OAuth is used  https://console.developers.google.com/project
```

The app icon also needs to deployed in various HD/Standard DPIs and sizes.

Is there a consolidated list anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much it.

This answer gives a nice list of the required images for the Play Store, as well as a description of what each should look like.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en